# [Service Worker]: How to retry post request if api call fail due to server down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, workbox, service-worker-events

I want to retry the POST API call when the previous API request failed due to an API down or internet failure.  I used setInterval to achieve that feature.  But the issue I'm facing is, the `setInternal` timer stops if the user force stop the chrome completely.

In this case, I want to automatically start the retry whenever the browser opens again.  How to achieve that.  I tried using periodic sync, but that's working only if I install the app.  Without installing the app, how to retry the API call? Is there any event available in **service worker** to listen for the **browser open**?

I tried to achieve it using the `periodicSync` event.  But in order to use that feature, users need to install our web app.  So is there any other feature available like `sync` that I can use without installing the app itself to achieve the desired behaviour?

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function (e) {
  if (e.tag === SYNC_USERS) return handleSyncUsers();
});

async function handleSyncUsers() {
  const syncResult = await syncUsers();
  const failedRequests = syncResult.filter(
    (res) => res.status === 'rejected'
  );
  
  if (failedRequests.length) {        
    return startPeriodicSync();
  } else {
    return clearPeriodicSync();
  }
}    

const startPeriodicSync = () => {
  periodicSyncTimer = setInterval(handleSyncUsers, 5000);
};

const clearPeriodicSync = () => {
  clearInterval(periodicSyncTimer);
  periodicSyncTimer = null;
};
```

Comment: Service workers have a [periodicSync event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/periodicSync) which can be used to trigger updates at a given [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PeriodicSyncManager). The browser support however is not that great (yet)

Comment: Hi @Reyno, Thank you for your answer. 
 Actually I tried periodicSnc before itself.  But in order to use that users have to install our web app right.  Is there any feature in the service worker that I can use without installing the app for retry? Can you help me with this?